# Using python I would like to know how to delete the first occurrence of a character between two strings in a file

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed

For example if I had some file:

```
OPEN(
,a
,b
) CLOSE
OPEN(
c
) CLOSE
OPEN(
,d
,e
,f
) CLOSE
```

I would like to remove the first occurrence of the character ',' following each 'OPEN(' but only if it occurs before the next ') CLOSE' such that the resulting file would look like:

```
OPEN(
a
,b
) CLOSE
OPEN(
c
) CLOSE
OPEN(
d
,e
,f
) CLOSE
```

Any thoughts on how I should approach? I have tried using regex, but I don't know how to specify conditions. Could some combination of awk & sed be used?

attempted regex solution:

```
pattern = r'WITH \(([^)]+),([^)]+)\) AS'
replacement = r'WITH (\1\2) AS'
sql_content_modified = re.sub(pattern, replacement, sql_content)
```

ended up solving with something like:

```
# Read the SQL file
    with open(f'{filename}', 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    content_modified = content.replace('(\n,', '(')
    content_modified = re.sub('--<([a-z]*.*[A-Z]*)>', '', content)  # removes the --<*> lines
    # Write the modified content back to the file
    with open(f'{filename}', 'w') as file:
        file.write(content_modified)
    remove_empty_lines_from_file(filename)

    # now do the same but replace "WITH (\n," with "WITH (\n" ...
    with open(f'{filename}', 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    content_modified = content.replace('(\n,', '(\n')
    with open(f'{filename}', 'w') as file:
        file.write(content_modified)
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Are you only looking for the comma `,` after the `(` symbol? An initial approach could be just replace the `(,` by a `(` directly.

Comment: Is the `,` always on the next line?

Comment: Have you considered `sql_content.replace('(\n,', '(')`?

Comment: @JRiggles exactly what I used in js question before this one `replace(/\(\n,/g,'(\n')`

Comment: @DhamankarTejas Yep! Same idea, just without RegEx

Comment: @JRiggles  + Latra great suggestions. Ended up using each. I also will modify the question in case it helps someone else down the road - turns out I also had some cases where I had empty lines or some garbage starting with --<*> before I hit that first comma I wanted to remove so the approach I ended up implementing includes some bonus. Thanks for getting me un-stuck -- & add your answers so I can accept :)

Comment: Your subject starts `Using python` but your tags include `awk` and `sed` - what are you looking for, just python or any Unix tool or something else? Whatever it is, please [edit] your question to match.

Answer (score 4):

In GNU `awk` with your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Where I am setting `RS` to `(^|\n)OPEN\\(\n,*[^\n]*\n[^)]*\\) *CLOSE` as per requirement and then playing around with RT to get the required output.

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZsFxA/1) for used regex for understanding purposes, note `awk` we need to double escape but in regex site single escape works, so that's why regex looks little different here.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)OPEN\\(\n,*[^\n]*\n[^)]*\\) *CLOSE' '
RT{
  sub(/^\n/,"",RT)
  sub(/,/,"",RT)
  print RT
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient but it those work. (assuming a file named "test.txt" in the same directory as the .py file)

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

newLines = []
flag = False
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if(flag):
        if(lines[index+1] != ') CLOSE\n'):
            line = line.strip(',')
        flag = False
    if(line == "OPEN(\n"):
        flag = True
    newLines.append(line)
print(newLines)
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    for line in newLines:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/OPEN/{:a;N;/CLOSE/!ba;s/,//}' file
```

Match the string `OPEN` then gather up further lines until one matching `CLOSE`. Then substitute the first `,` with nothing.

N.B. If there is no closing string, the remainder of the file will be read then printed once a read on the end-of-file is encounter i.e. the `N` command is enacted after the `$` address.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple python script with comments for explanation.**

`delete_key.txt - input data file`

`delete_key_formatted.txt - output file with the formatted data`

```
def format_data():
    char_remove = ","
    all_chars = []  # final list
    with open("delete_key.txt") as f:
        cleaned = f.readlines()
        is_open = False
        chars_in_between = []  # temp to store each iterate (open to close or open to open)
        for clean in cleaned:
            if "OPEN" in clean:
                if is_open:  # if we have reached open without close
                    all_chars.extend(chars_in_between)
                    chars_in_between = []
                is_open = True

            '''
            (Optional)We can add (if is_open:) condition to skip all the lines that come without open
            '''
            chars_in_between.append(clean)  # collecting all lines

            if "CLOSE" in clean and is_open:  # if we reached close after hitting open
                is_open = False
                chars_in_between[1] = chars_in_between[1][1:] if chars_in_between[1][0] == char_remove else chars_in_between[1]  # remove the first occurrence of the character ',' following each 'OPEN(' but only if it occurs before the next ') CLOSE'
                all_chars.extend(chars_in_between)  # appending to the current iterate to final list
                chars_in_between = []  # reset the temp current iterate
        if len(chars_in_between) > 0:  # if we reached end of file without close
            all_chars.extend(chars_in_between)

    with open("delete_key_formatted.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(all_chars)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    format_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use regular expression with zero-length assertions following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
OPEN(
,a
,b
) CLOSE
OPEN(
c
) CLOSE
OPEN(
,d
,e
,f
) CLOSE
```

then

```
import re
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    text = f.read()
with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(re.sub(r'(?<=\(\n),(?=.*CLOSE)', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

do change `file.txt` content to

```
OPEN(
a
,b
) CLOSE
OPEN(
c
) CLOSE
OPEN(
d
,e
,f
) CLOSE
```

Explanation: read content of whole file into `text`, then replace all `,`-s which are after bracket-newline (this is *positive lookbehind*) and before zero-or-more any character followed by `CLOSE` (this is *positive lookahead*) with any character *including* newline (`re.DOTALL`), then write result to file with same name.
Consult [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) if you want to know more about zero-length assertions available.

*(tested in Python 3.10.6)*

Answer (score 0):

To preface, I am misunderstanding the following condition.

> *"... but only if it occurs before the next ') CLOSE' ..."*

Nevertheless, you can use the following to match your expected result.

```
(?s)(?<=OPEN\(.),
```

Output

```
OPEN(
a
,b
) CLOSE
OPEN(
c
) CLOSE
OPEN(
d
,e
,f
) CLOSE
```